# Selenium + Chrome + Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I want to save a webpage. This looks simples. I used the code below. This opens the browser but the page is not saved.

Why?

When this works, where the file will be saved?

Thanks

Detais:
Chrome 68.0.3440.106 - 64 bits

ChromeDriver 2.41

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Selenium\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get('https://automatetheboringstuff.com')

ActionChains(browser).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('s').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

Comment: Code better be in code format

Comment: Sorry. Now is better?

Comment: selenium can not save a file in the way you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to save the html of a page, you can get that from the page source.

```
html = browser.page_source
```

and if you want to write this to a file, you can do this:

```
html_file = open('some_file_name.html', 'w')
html_file.write(html)
```

Comment: I have to download the complete page (images,, stylesheets, etc)